# Is there a way I can delete all data from a sharepoint list using cURL

Tags: rest, sharepoint, curl

Is there any simple command to delete data from a sharepoint list? I know we can delete 1 row at a time by explicituly defining its ID. I am looking for some thing like DELETEALL etc..

Here is the command to delete 1 row from SP list

```
url --ntlm -X DELETE http://nusername:password@server_name/sites/eTMFDev/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Facilities(765) -k
```

Comment: No,  this will not work

Comment: How do we manage updates to the existing lists if there is no Delete all option with cURL. We have 1000 rows in SP and some of those rows should be updated and new rows from text file will be added to the existing list